# Ruby - how to join output from a Rails command?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, join

There are multiple calculations I'd like to be able to perform on my database, all centred around a user id, but I don't know how to recombine them after.

Let's say I have three tables for `User`, `Purchases`, and `DiscountUsage`. I want to find the last date a user made a purchase and the total number of discounts used. I would run two separate commands:

```
User.joins(:purchases).group("users.id").select("users.id", "MAX(purchases.purchase_date)")
User.joins(:discount_usages).group("users.id").select("users.id", "COUNT(*)")
```

I want my final output to be one table though, joined on `users.id`, but the output from `select` isn't the right data type to work on with Rails functions. How can I represent that the `users.id` values from both calls are the same and thus join them based on those columns?

Comment: Have you looked at [merge](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/SpawnMethods.html#method-i-merge)?

Comment: @jvillian this is similar, but it requires the inputs to be in ActiveRecord::Relation format. I don't see how I can perform grouped calculations while maintaining that format.

Comment: Can you please show a sample of the two entities (arrays, maybe? or hashes?) you are attempting to combine and what you want the result to look like?

Comment: @jvillian sorry upon closer inspection I think this is mostly what I'm looking for but I'll have to read the documentation to understand better how to use it. Do you know if there's anything like a "left_merge" though? Similar to a left_join, where it will merge on common values but not omit ones that don't match?

Comment: Again, if you show some example data, it's a lot easier to help. Otherwise, it's sort of guess work.

Answer (score 0):

You can select aggregates from joined tables and access them in the model by using aliases:

```
@users = User.joins(:purchases, :discount_usages)
            .select(
              "users.id", 
              "MAX(purchases.purchase_date) AS latest_purchase",
              "COUNT(discount_usages.*) AS discount_usages_count"
            )
            .group("users.id")
```

If you want to hydrate the other attributes of the records select `users.*` instead of just `users.id`.

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Id</th>
      <th>Latest Purchase</th>
      <th>Discount usages</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <% @users.each do |user| %>
    <tr>
      <td><%= user.id %></td>
      <td><%= user.latest_purchase %></td>
      <td><%= user.discount_usages_count %></td>   
    </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

> I want my final output to be one table though, joined on users.id, but
>   the output from select isn't the right data type to work on with Rails
>   functions.

Not sure quite what you mean here. This example will return a collection of user records just like a normal query.
If you want a "raw" result with just an array of arrays use `.pluck` instead of `.select`.

Answer (score 0):

I assume a User may not have any purchases and not all purchases use discount codes.

However, you want a full listing of each user with their last purchase date and total discount usages over all purchases. You may need to use a right join.

Something like:

```
query = User.select('users.id AS user_id', 'MAX(purchases.purchase_date) AS last_purchase_date', 'COUNT(discount_usages.id) AS total_discount_usages')
  .joins('LEFT JOIN purchases ON purchases.user_id = users.id')
  .joins('LEFT JOIN discount_usages ON discount_usages.user_id = purchases.user_id')
  .group('users.id')
  .to_sql
```

Then in order to grab the fields you could use:

```
rows = ApplicationRecord.connection.select_all(query).to_hash
```

https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#select-all

This will give you an array of hashes with keys: 'user_id', 'last_purchase_date', 'total_discount_usages'.

```
...
<% rows.each do |row| %>
  <% row.symbolize_keys! %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= row[:user_id] %></td>
    <td><%= row[:last_purchase_date] %></td>
    <td><%= row[:total_discount_usages] %></td>
  <tr>
...
```